# Compiler error about conflicting parameter types and incompatible conversion for the same method

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm getting a warning when trying to use a method from Chartboost:

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'didCacheInterstitial:': 'CBLocation' vs 'NSString *__strong'

at the following method:

```
- (void)didCacheInterstitial:(NSString *)location {
NSLog(@"interstitial cached at location %@", location);   
}
```

and

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'CBLocation'`

When doing the following:

```
[cb cacheInterstitial:@"Main Menu"];
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is to encourage developers to use the preset locations found in the CBLocation enum in the header file.

However, the latest Chartboost SDK is backwards compatible with interstitial calls that pass an NSString parameter.

For example, the following call will work fine despite throwing a warning:

`[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:@"foobar"];`

Some trickery in the SDK will automatically cast @"foobar" as a long, so there you can ignore the warning.

In regards to logging, you can consider using `NSLog(@"%@", location);` to ensure human readable output of the location instead of incomprehensible numbers. As above, this will work despite the warning.

Full Disclosure: I work for Chartboost.

Comment: So you're using the address of a literal string as an "index"...what happens when someone dynamically constructs the string later, instead of passing the literal? What do you tell people who use `-Werror`?

Answer (score 2):

The header file that declares `didCacheInterstitial:` says this:

```
- (void)didCacheInterstitial:(CBLocation)location;
```

which does not match your implementation. The definition of the method must match the declaration.

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean the actual chartboost tutorial is wrong? https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/ios/namedlocations

Comment: Something's wrong, either the tutorial or the header. I can't really tell which.

Comment: I see. How would you reocmmend I fix this?

Comment: Assuming this protocol consists of methods that their service is calling on your code, trust the code rather than the tutorial, and email them for clarification.

Comment: Thank you! I went ahead and did just that by converting the NSString to a CBLocation and properly NSLogging it using %llu rather than %@.